# Switch back and forth between last active two programs with AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to get a single tap of <kbd>ALT</kbd> to switch back and forth between programs, but not interfere with or break the native functionality of holding the key, however `A_PriorKey` [below] only seems to consider keyboard keys and not mouse buttons or clicks.

How I can get mouse keys to be considered as well?

- The goal is to switch back and forth between the last active two programs only if no other keys were pressed when <kbd>ALT</kbd> is held down:

  ```bat
  ~$LAlt Up::
  {
    ToolTip, % A_PriorKey 
    if (A_PriorKey = "LAlt")
    {
      send, !{Tab}
    }
    Return
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly exclude combinations by setting a flag in hotkeys for each of those combinations.

Your example did not work for me, so first option is to use a key other than <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

**Option 1. Use another key**

Here I use <kbd>L SHIFT</kbd>:

```powershell
sendmode input

discard := 0

<+lbutton::
  discard := 1
  send +{lbutton}
return

<+rbutton::
  discard := 1
  send +{rbutton}
return

~lshift up::
  tooltip %a_priorkey% -- %discard%
  if (a_priorkey = "LShift" && discard = 0) {
    send !{tab}
  }
  discard:= 0
return
```

**Option 2. Using LAlt (with some trick)**

It is still possible to do with <kbd>L ALT</kbd>, but it is more complicated, requiring a trick to block Windows' hardcoded `Alt up` menu invocation. Combined with the above method:

```powershell
discard := 0

<!lbutton::
    discard := 1
    send !{lbutton}
return

<!rbutton::
    discard := 1
    send !{rbutton}
return

LAlt::
    send {LAlt down}
return

~LAlt up::
    if (a_priorkey = "LAlt" && discard = 0) {
        send !{tab}
    }
    send {LAlt up}
    discard := 0
return
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't try and worry about detecting other keys, and simply use a timer value to make sure you press on/off of <kbd>ALT</kbd> in a fairly short time, it could work.

- One drawback of what you're trying to do is if you activate a file, menu with it showing, then wanted to clear it with an <kbd>ALT</kbd> down/up, it wouldn't do so, regardless of your implementation, if you are trying to map a down/up press of <kbd>ALT</kbd> to be <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> instead.

You can try the below, but it requires a short on/off <kbd>ALT</kbd> and doesn't check for other keys being pressed, also allowing you to do multiple short on/off presses to trigger a multiple <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> and switch back to more than just the last active program; for example, two quick on/off presses gets you to the second-last program and changes the order of the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> program list.

- Change the `deltaTime` comparison constant if it doesn't trigger quite right, and enable the `deltaTime` tooltip to see what your trigger presses average out to for setting the comparison constant:

  ```powershell
  ~$LAlt::
    SetTimer, SendAltTab, Off
    If !triggered
      ; Ignore subsequent triggers if user holds down, until Alt Up is triggered
      myTimer:=A_TickCount
    triggered:=True
  Return

  ~$LAlt Up::
    triggered:=False
        deltaTime := A_TickCount-myTimer

    ;ToolTip % "deltaTime=" deltaTime " (ms)"

    If (deltaTime>300) {
      ; Set the max time to not exceed before ignoring (300 - 500ms usually works ok)
      sendCount:=0
      Return
    }

    SetTimer, SendAltTab, -200
    sendCount+=1
  Return

  SendAltTab:
    SendInput, !{Tab %sendCount%}
    ToolTip % "sendCount=" sendCount
    sendCount:=0
  Return
  ```

  - **Note:** The `200ms` timeout [`SetTimer, SendAltTab, -200`] is how long you have to trigger an additional back-to-back press for multiple <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> presses; if you never want to use multiple <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> presses, disable the `200ms` time delay [set to `-1` or include the code directly] so it will never have a `sendCount` more than `1`.

    - This makes it a bit snappier on triggering an <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd>, but you will only be able to trigger a single <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd> with this simpler implementation, no matter how many times or how fast you hit ALT.
  - If not wanting to use this for multiple <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd>, you can adjust the `200ms` timer to require faster back-to-back presses with a snappier execution on the final press, since it will time out faster), or you could slow it down to not have to be as fast on a back-to-back press (with a slightly delayed execution on the final press, since it will time out slower).  The timer values below felt pretty natural after trying it out though.

If you need to actually check for other keys, you could do an alternate implementation to set a variable with **<kbd>↓ ALT</kbd>** that would get unset by any other key getting pressed, then check the variable again on **<kbd>↑ ALT</kbd>**.

- Another means is to check `A_PriorKey` on **<kbd>↓ ALT</kbd>** to see if it has changed with **<kbd>↑ ALT</kbd>**, however this wouldn't work if you did the same <kbd>ALT</kbd>+`<whatever>` keystroke twice in a row since it would look like a key hadn't been pressed, triggering an <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB ⭾</kbd>.